# PostgreSQL 9.2 set enable_nestloop has no effect

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I try to changing nestloop

```
set enable_nestloop=1
```

When I look

```
show enable_nestloop;
 enable_nestloop 
-----------------
 on
(1 row)
```

all is ok. But it has no effect.
If changing this param in config file and then reload config from cli, all work fine. 
Why *set* not working for me?

Comment: What do you mean with "*has no effect*"?

Comment: Query planning not changed

Comment: You did see the comment [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html): "*It is impossible to suppress nested-loop joins entirely, but turning this variable off discourages the planner from using one if there are other methods available*" (plus: the default is `on` anyway)

Comment: My mistake, bad example. I know that it's "on" by default. I needed in application turning it to "off" for some queries and after return to "on". Maybe you know how to implement it?

Comment: If you have a slow query, it's probably better to post the query and get help on how to improve it: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: It's not so simple. I use postgre as DB for [1C](http://www.1c.ru), and I can't tuning many queries for increasing speed. Max what i can - turning to "off" and "on" state  of `nestloop`.

Comment: Are you sure using nested loops would result in a more efficient query plan than the one you're seeing? If you're _positive_ the planner is doing the wrong thing, make sure statistics for the relevant tables are up to date, and maybe bump up the collection target.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I tested speed of some operations in 1C with different state of nestloop. And in result part of queries working faster with disabled nestloop, other when it enable. That kind of problem not only at me, but no one didn't write solution.

Answer (score 0):

`enable_nestloop` is a testing parameter. It is on by default, which is why turning it on had no effect. It's there so you can turn it *off* to tell the query planner "please don't use a nested loop unless you have no other way to execute this query". It does this by forcing the cost estimate for nested loops very high.

This is *not* a query hint you can use to say "please use a nested loop for this query". It doesn't work like that.

It's strongly recommended that you *not* use these testing parameters for production use. Forcing a plan now may have unfortunate consequences later. If at all possible, use the cost parameters like `random_page_cost` and `effective_cache_size` to guide the planner into choosing the most appropriate plan its self.

If you *absolutely must* use params like this in your app, use `SET LOCAL` to set them just within one transaction.

There is *no way* to set them for a single statement then automatically unset them. That's partly because they're just not meant to be used that way. They're designed *not* to be query hints.

Comment: Thanks, Craig, and would you please let me know the best option to disable the nested loop for just one query?

Comment: @LingYanMeng It's in the answer above.